# Prove that the ring $\mathbb Z $ [x] (ring of all polynomials with integer coefficients) has unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I know that the existence of unity implies non existence of zero divisor.

Is the converse true? (because I have prooved the latter - its quite simple).

If not; how do I go about this?

Comment: "existence of unity implies non existence of zero divisor." Not true at all. The ring $\Bbb Z_4$ has both unity $1$ and a zero divisor $2$. And $2\Bbb Z$ has neither. So there is no relation (at least not that simple) between the existence of unity and the existence of zero divisors.

Comment: What definition of $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ are you using where this isn't immediate?

Answer (score 0):

The constant polynomial $1=1\cdot x^0$ is a unit. The ring is certainly an integral domain, being a subring of the PID $\Bbb Q[x]$. Also, $R[x]$ is an integral domain if and only if $R$ is an integral domain, see this duplicate:

[Prove that $R[x]$ is an integral domain if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604247/prove-that-rx-is-an-integral-domain-if-and-only-if-r-is-an-integral-domain?rq=1)

Since $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain, also $\Bbb Z[x]$ is. Also the units of $\Bbb Z[x]$ are the units of $\Bbb Z$. For this, see here:

[What are the units of Z[x]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591906/what-are-the-units-of-zx)